# How to fix CSS spacing between images

Tags: css

Trying to modify the images displayed at a wordpress widget. I managed to change the image size to 90x45px but for some reason, the space allocated to the image is still 90x90px, so there is too much space between each post within the widget.

http://aviationtribune.com/airlines/pacific-and-oceania/cobham-takes-delivery-of-its-first-bombardier-q400-aircraft/

Bottom, right.

Changed the CSS to:

```
.feedzy-rss .rss_item .rss_image {
float: left;
position: relative;
border: none;
text-decoration: none;
width:90px; 
   height:45px;

}
```

and

```
.feedzy-rss .rss_item .rss_image span {
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
width:90px; 
height:45px;
background-position: 50%;
background-size: cover

}
```

Inspecting the code I get the following right where the image is:

```
<div class="rss_image" style="width:90px; height:90px">
```

So it seems to me that that "style" is the one ruining it, but I cannot seem to find where that is coming from.

Anyone could help? Thank you and regards.

Comment: http://aviationtribune.com/airlines/pacific-and-oceania/cobham-takes-delivery-of-its-first-bombardier-q400-aircraft/

there is not RSS widget and mentioned images on this page

Comment: Just cleared the cache. It should be showing now. For me, it showed fine on Safari but not any of the other browsers. You should be able to see it now. Managed to fix the space issue, but I am also trying to change the colour of the links for this specific widget unsuccessfully. Any tips?

Comment: Yes, the widget appears now. To change the color of this widget links, just add the following code to any css file:          .feedzy-rss .title a { color: #123456;}        where 123456 is your color code in HEX format.  Concerning images - it seems you've rebuilt the widget layout and loads images as backgrounds. They appears well from my side in Chrome and FF:  https://prnt.sc/p00tpj